# Only see the first referenced UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

How it is possible that only the **first** UserControl ni the WindowsFormsHost is shown in the GUI while the seconde one is still hidden?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf_zoom0="clr-namespace:LowLightGrab;assembly=LowLightGrab" 
    xmlns:wf_zoom1="clr-namespace:LowLightGrab;assembly=LowLightGrab" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost Height="154" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="wf_zoom0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215" >
        <wf_zoom0:UserControl1/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>

    <WindowsFormsHost Height="161" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,138,0,0" Name="wf_zoom1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223" >
        <wf_zoom1:UserControl1/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

Comment: remove your margin

Margin="251,138,0,0"

Comment: @eranotzap Why should this have an influence?

Comment: Because both of them are shown  , it's just that you've pushed the second one 251 pixels to the right , so you don't see it .

Answer (score 0):

Other than removing the margin as Eran added, You should add Rows to the Grid and place each of the elements in its own row, something lile this:

```
<Window x:Class="ComboboxRectangles.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:wf_zoom0="clr-namespace:LowLightGrab;assembly=LowLightGrab" 
xmlns:wf_zoom1="clr-namespace:LowLightGrab;assembly=LowLightGrab" 
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Column="0" Height="154" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="wf_zoom0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215" >
            <wf_zoom0:UserControl1/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>

        <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Column="1" Height="161" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,138,0,0" Name="wf_zoom1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223" >
            <wf_zoom1:UserControl1/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: The result is still the same it only shows the first declared UserControl - with or without the margin. Does it maybe depend of the UserControl itself? It is an image read from a Camera.

Comment: Could you try placing a button instead?

Comment: place a button where? I can place in each column a single button and both are shown but only (the first one) WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: So the second one is faulty. Check its content. You can also set its background color to blue and see that you can see it.

Comment: Thats correct. I can see both backgrounds when I set for each a different color. The only thing what does not show up is the second UserControl.

Comment: So you probably have something wrong with its content.

Comment: ok but what could it be? The content itself is good because I can see it in my first column.

Comment: I am guessing that you are adding the same image to both of them that sometimes causes problems.

Comment: The UserControl code is a bit long. It is a picturebox where a camera image is rendered into. Maybe it is easier this way that I am using only one UserControl and make a "copy" in the WPF environment and display it as a normal image?

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

Comment: That's hard without seeing the code. What is the type you are using to show the image?

Comment: It is a bitmap image.